# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk - failed due to missing certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the same EBS instance for years.

Today it started failing, when I restart it.

I checked and the reason is there is a certificated included in load balancer, and this certificate is deleted.

So it can not create the server, because it can not find this certificate.

I tried to remove it from configuration, but it says "Instance status must be read" but it can not be ready, because certificate fails it.

Im in an infinitive loop.
How can I remove certificate from my EBS. And reinstall the application?

Comment: I don't know a lot about Elastic Beanstalk, but I guess your options are to get a new certificate (not sure how with EB - simple with ACM) or just recreate the instance and get a fresh environment. If that doesn't suit then you best contact AWS Support for help.